# Saving file pathname to mySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, file-upload

Sorry if this question is really long winded but i want to be as detailed as i can in hope of getting an answer to my problem.

Basically i have a multipart form that i want to add file upload capabilities to. I have the form created, a function to handle saving the image to a directory and also a script to handle posting the form values to the database. My problem is that the i have the image storing where i want it to now on submit of the form but none of the form values are being sent to the database. I think my problem is that i am trying to store the new path name as a variable which i then call in the POST script but i think this is wrong?

The error that is thrown up is:

**Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_design_cms\create_wireframe.php on line 13**

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form action="create_wireframe.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <!-- page_title -->



        <p>
            <label>Title:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" class="text small" name="wireframe_title" id="wireframe_title" value=""  />
            <span class="note">*required</span>
        </p>    

        <!-- page_meta_title -->


        <p>
            <label>Browser Title:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" class="text small" name="browser_title" id="browser_title" value=""  >
            <span class="note">*required</span>
        </p>

        <!-- url_key -->            



        <p>
            <label>Permanent Link:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" class="text small" name="url_key" id="url_key" value=""/>
        </p>

        <!-- page_image -->

        <div style="float:left" >
            <!-- wireframe_type -->

            <p>
                <label>Type:</label><br/>
                <select name="wireframe_type" id="wireframe_type" class="styled" style="width:240px">
                    <option value="design"  > Design Draft</option>
                    <option value="wireframe" selected > Wireframe</option>                          
                </select>
                <span class="note">*required</span>
            </p>                                            

        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div class="message info"><p>
            Allowed file types for upload: jpg,jpeg,gif,png.<br/>
            Max file size: 10Mb<br/>
            Picture size: 4096x4096 px
        </p></div>


        <p>
            <label>Upload Image:</label><br/>                   
            <input type="file" name="page_main_image" id="page_main_image" value=""  />
        </p>


        <!-- page_bg_color -->
        <p>
            <label>Color:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" class="text small" maxlength="6" size="6" style="width:60px" id="colorpickerField"  name="page_bg_color" value="ffffff" />
            <span id="colorSelector" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:7px 10px;">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="note">*required</span>
        </p>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="submit small" value="Save" name="submit" />
        </p>
     </form>
```

Here's the php script 'create_wireframe.php' handling the form data:

```
<?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Process the form
    $image = upload_file();

    $wireframe_title = mysql_prep($_POST["wireframe_title"]);
    $browser_title = $_POST["browser_title"];
    $url_key = $_POST["url_key"];
    $wireframe_type = $_POST["wireframe_type"];
    $image = $_POST["page_main_image"];
$page_bg_color = $_POST ["page_bg_color"];

    $query  = "INSERT INTO wireframes (";
    $query .= " wireframe_title, browser_title, url_key, wireframe_type, page_main_image, page_bg_color";
    $query .= " ) VALUES (";
    $query .= " '{$wireframe_title}', '{$browser_title}', '{$url_key}', '{$wireframe_type}', '{$image}', '{$page_bg_color}' ";
    $query .= ")";

    echo $query;

    try { $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'Caught exception: '+  $e->getMessage()+ "\n";
    }
    //Test if there was a query error
    if ($result) {
        //Success
        // would normally use a redirect ie redirect_to("somepage.php");
        //$message = "Subject created.";
        redirect_to("wireframes.php");
    }else {
        //failure
        //$message = "Subject creation failed.";
        //redirect_to("add_project.php");
        echo $query;
    }
} else {
    // This is probably a GET request
    redirect_to("add_edit_wireframe.php");
}
?>

<?php
// Close database connection
if(isset($connection)){ mysqli_close($connection); }
?>
```

And finally the function i created for handling the storing of my images in the directory:

```
function upload_file(){
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["page_main_image"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["size"] < 200000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["page_main_image"]["error"] . "<br>";;
        }
        else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["page_main_image"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["page_main_image"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["page_main_image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kb<br>";

            if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["page_main_image"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["page_main_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["page_main_image"]["tmp_name"],
                    "uploads/" . $_FILES["page_main_image"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["page_main_image"]["name"];
                $image="{$_FILES['page_main_image']['name']}";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }

    return $image;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure but i think the problem is something to do with the variable $image that im trying to store the path name in? At the end of the function i return the variable and in the post script then try to take this value and post it into the 'page_main_image' field in the database but clearly i'm doing something wrong?

Sorry again for long post but any help you can give me will really be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with uploaded files, such as images, you need to use $_FILES instead of $_POST to access the data.

Check out this [documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

**Edit**

You need to change the main logic.

```
$image = upload_file(); //Good

$wireframe_title = mysql_prep($_POST["wireframe_title"]);
$browser_title = $_POST["browser_title"];
$url_key = $_POST["url_key"];
$wireframe_type = $_POST["wireframe_type"];

//Delete this, you're throwing out the value from upload_file()
$image = $_POST["page_main_image"];
```

Comment: In the function that handles the storing of the file i have used the super global $_FILES, this is all working fine. the problem is i want to take the pathname of where the image has been stored and post this into the database. I have tried storing it in a variable "$image" but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Well it looks like you set `$image = upload_file()` and then immediately throw away that value and set `$image = $_POST["page_main_image"]`. Perhaps you left that second part in there by accident?

Comment: This is where im going wrong, im not sure what im supposed to do? At the end of the function i return "$image" which im hoping holds the pathname for the current image uploaded, i then need to take that and send it to the database. I assumed this was how i do it? Obviously not!

Comment: Two things. I'm not sure why you're writing `$image="{$_FILES['page_main_image']['name']}";` instead of just saying `$image= $_FILES['page_main_image']['name'];`. But that shouldn't matter much. What I'm saying is you need to remove this line: `$image = $_POST["page_main_image"];`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that has fixed the error, the data is still not posting to the db though. I think this may be a fault to do with the structure of the table however so if i fix this and it solves the problem i'll mark your answer as correct! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: No problem, if you want to be sure, throw `echo $image;` just below `$image = upload_file();` so you can make sure `$image` has an appropriate value. If it does, then it's just a DB error somewhere.